# SAWarning: Multiple rows returned with uselist=False for lazily-loaded attribute 'Similarity.tag1'

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I get the following warning from SQLAlchemy and I wonder what the problem is:

```
\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\strategies.py:911: SAWarning: Multiple rows returned with uselist=False for lazily-loaded attribute 'Similarity.tag1' 
  util.warn(
\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\strategies.py:911: SAWarning: Multiple rows returned with uselist=False for lazily-loaded attribute 'Similarity.tag' 
  util.warn(
```

My ORM classes looks like this:

```py
class Similarity(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'similarities'

    tag_id_1 = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('tags.id'), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    tag_id_2 = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('tags.id'), primary_key=True, nullable=False, index=True)
    value = db.Column(DOUBLE, nullable=False)

    tag = db.relationship('Tag', primaryjoin='Similarity.tag_id_1 == Tag.id', backref='tag_similarities')
    tag1 = db.relationship('Tag', primaryjoin='Similarity.tag_id_2 == Tag.id', backref='tag_similarities_0')


class Tag(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tags'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False, autoincrement=True)
    language_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('languages.id'), primary_key=True, nullable=False, index=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(45), nullable=False, index=True)

    language = db.relationship('Language', primaryjoin='Tag.language_id == Language.id', backref='tags')
```

I use `SQLAlchemy 1.3.22` and Python 3.8. Can you please explain what the message is about and how I can fix this?

Comment: _"Multiple rows returned with uselist=False"_ means you declared this relation to be 1-to-1, but there is more than 1 found in the data base.

Comment: But I don't set `use_list=False`. And I guess default is `True`, right?

Comment: The default for [`uselist`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.uselist) is not `True`. The default is _"determined automatically"_, the specs say.

Comment: You are right. I think I got an idea what the problem could be here: The primary key of `Tag` is not just `id`. Both columns, `id` and `language_id` form the primary key.
Therefore, the relationships return more than one tag, for example one Tag with `id` 1 in english and one in spanish.

Comment: The problem is if I set `uselist=True` I get the error `TypeError: Incompatible collection type: Tag is not list-like`. So can I fix this?

Comment: This warning does not seem like a problem to me at least. Your tag table is using a composite PK with 2 columns, forming a unique PK. This is saying you have non unique relationship between languages and Tag, but is this so much of a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @zvone said, the relationships `tag` and `tag1` can point to multiple tags because `Tag` has two primary columns. That's what the warning message is about: *The relationships aren't unique*.

Therefore, the solution is either to remove these relationships or to make them unique.

Comment: How can I make relationship unique?